# How to use .numberformat in VBA with variable text

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

I am writing a worksheet_change sub to change the formatting of a cell that contains text.
The text is the customer name, and the customer receives price lists from two of our brands. So I have two customer entries in my sheet for them, as "Customer (Brand 1)" and "Customer (Brand 2)", whereas for another customer who is single-branded they have only one entry "Customer". These customers are electrical wholesalers and we supply them with cable, for some context...

The two entries are to differentiate them on the sheet but I would not like the Brand name to appear on the price list. It should only display their company name and the branding will be covered by the price list itself.

When using the macro recorder to manually change the formatting to just "Customer" it returns the following code:

```
Cells(7,3).NumberFormat = ";;;""Customer"""
```

So I use this as a template and recreate it using the "target" cell which is "Customer (Brand)":

```
Brand = Replace(Target, " (Brand)", "")
Cells(7, 3).NumberFormat = ";;;" & """""" & Brand & """"""
```

When I mouse-over this in debug mode(?) the pop-up box reads exactly as the code above given by the recorder. But it doesn't work. I receive the error "Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class".

My full code (any other tips appreciated!):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Row <> 7 Or Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub

Dim Debrand As String
Debrand = Replace(Target.Value, " (Brand)", "")

Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(7, 3).NumberFormat = ";;;" & """""" & Debrand & """"""
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Many thanks.

Comment: To many `"`, you only need to escape once: `Cells(7, 3).NumberFormat = ";;;" & """" & Debrand & """"`

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Not 100% on how it works as it can be confusing to look at!

Comment: `"` is the String delimiter indicator in VBA source code, so if you need a `"` inside a String, you need to indicate to VBA that it shouldn't be considered as a String delimiter, but as a simple `"`. To to that you **escape** it by doubling it. In `";;;""Customer"""`, the 1st and last `"` are String delimiters, and the other `""` are **escaped** `"` in the string. The content of the String itself is `;;;"Customer"`, and that's what you should try to reproduce, not `;;;""Customer""`.