# How to use .numberformat in VBA with variable of type double as comperator

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

Dear all i want to format my cell based on the Cell value. There are 3 possible Conditions:

```
Cell is larger than 0.05 -> the Value should stay the same but be fromated to 0.0
Cell is smaller than a variable (called Threshold) -> the Value should be replaced with a String "a.C."
Cell is Zero -> the Value should be replaced with a Dash"
```

I figured out how to do this without a vavriable in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65129793/vba-numberformat-muliple-condtions-to-format-cell-value). How to add a text string .numberformat in vba is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56426808/how-to-use-numberformat-in-vba-with-variable-text)!

This:

```
.NumberFormat = "[=0]---;[<0.05] ""a.C."";0.0 "
```

Does work, while this:

```
Dim threshold as Double

threshold = 0.05

.NumberFormat = "[=0]---;[<threshold] ""a.C."";0.0 "
```

Does not work. I guess i nedd to either pass a special variable typoe to the "<" comperator or i need to escape the variable somehow?

A hint would be really appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `threshold` is part of your number format string. Basically everything that is within quotes is not touched by VBA - except for the double double quotes that tells VBA to use a quote character within the string  rather than end the string.

To put the content of the variable into a string, use string concatenation. This is done in VBA using the "&" operator:

```
.NumberFormat = "[=0]---;[<" & threshold & "] ""a.C."";0.0 "
```

However, as Double can be a little bit nasty because of rounding, it's maybe better to use the format command to output it in the wanted form (eg 2 digits after the decimal). And it's usually a good idea to use an intermediate variable that you can easily check with the debugger:

```
Dim myNumberFormat as string
myNumberFormat  = "[=0]---;[<" _
                & format(threshold, "0.00") _
                & "] ""a.C."";0.0 "
.NumberFormat = myNumberFormat
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this does not work. the `d.dd` formats the variable as some type of Date i guess? But even if i do `& format(threshold, "0.00") _` the Numberformat that is passed to excel reads`[=0]---;[<0] "a.C.";0.0` if i check via rightclick-> format for the cell value i try to change?

Comment: The Variable myNumberFormat reads:`[=0]---;[<0,05]"a.C.";0.0` if i print it. So there are two quotes missing and there is a comma instead of a "dot". If i manually change it to `"[=0]---;[<0.05]""a.C."";0.0"` and use string dirclty it works.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, should be "0.00". Corrected my answer